# Could not initialize Tesseract API with language=eng for tess-two API

Tags: java, android, ocr, tesseract, tess-two

I'm trying to implement the tess-two api for my Android application and I'm getting this error no matter how I try to fix it:

> E/Tesseract(native): Could not initialize Tesseract API with language=eng!

I do have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the Manifest.

Also in TessBaseAPI.java file in the tess-two library, all the native functions shows

> Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function Java_com_googlecode_tesseract_android_TessBaseAPI_nativeClass

How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: @rmtheis I saved the trained data in my assets folder. so in /assets/tesseract/tessdata. I cloned the whole tessdata from github so I'm using whatever the current version is. As for calling init, i first copy everything from my assets folder to the sdcard, then call init with datapath /sdcard/tesseract.

Comment: @rmtheis since that message is not related to initialization failure, how should i fix it?

Comment: I copied the .traineddata file to tessdata/ inside the cache folder and then initialized it pointing to the cache dir.  It works for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you're targeting Android API level 23 (Android 6.0), you need to [get user permission](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) to access external storage.